# how to fix localstorage is not defined in nextjs redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am trying to use local storage in nextjs with redux, I know that With Next.js, components are rendered server-side. localStorage - or the window - is not available until rendered in a browser. That's why I used this `typeof window !== "undefined";` Now the error is showing `Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const clientSide = typeof window !== "undefined";

const initialState = {
  cart: clientSide
    ? localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems") || "{}")
      : []
    : [],
  cartTotal: 0,
  cartTotalQuantity: 0,
};
```

Comment: The solution for this question might fix your problem [NextJs LocalStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819721/next-js-access-localstorage-before-rendering-page)

Comment: This example shows how to integrate Redux with the power of Redux Persist in Next.js.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63276931/load-the-initial-state-with-localstorage-redux-next-js

Comment: Not able to solve the issue, can any one help me with code

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call `useEffect()` on your `index` page or wherever , then in the hook `dispatch` an `action` to update the `initial state`.